# Return data from anonymous class variables

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to achieve the results below. I'm constricted to using this class and it's methods to achieve it.

```
final class Trade {

    private $users_id;
    private $adj_id;

    public function display() {
        var_dump($this);    
    }

    public function setData($form_results) {
        foreach ($form_results as $var => $value) {
            $this->{$var} = $value;
        }
    }

    public function getData() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

The problem is calling `get_object_vars()` inside the class method. As expected it ignores the private variables I have set and returns an array of all the class variables both public and private due to its scope.

I'm trying to have the method return just the public anonymous variables. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
   foreach($this as $key => $value) {
       print "$key => $value\n";
   }
```

See details on http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save all the data to some private variable and return that?

If your object must have the data as it's properties, you can use `__get` and `__set` to read and set items in that array, and on outside it will look as though they were properties.